# Let's [clear] this tag out

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clear) is used on 1100 questions at present, including button color, preferences, console display, CSS, DLL hell, ListView controls, browser cache, and on and on the madness goes. There is no semantic consistency to it: it's just the literal English word "clear" in any of its numerous connotations. It has 5 followers, 4 users with more than one answer, 0 users with more than one question, and nothing in the wiki.

So is there any reason not to Kill It With Fire™?

Comment: The reasons you present are as... clear as glass.

Comment: @MarkGarcia, it's … clear … that you agree with me.

Comment: I am wondering what is the motivation of these 5 followers.

Comment: It is ... clear ... only to them?

Comment: "It's unclear what you're asking here."

Comment: I am tempted to close-vote this post as "Unclear what you're asking"

Comment: We need to keep meta … clear … of any needless burninate requests, certainly!

Comment: We really should clear this kind of clutter from StackOverflow.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you've got the all-clear to clear the tag out.  Clear?  ... Man, that doesn't even sound like a real word anymore...

Comment: Nuke it from orbit... it's the only way to be sure.

Comment: Shesh. It's clear you all have been watching "The Princess Bride" too often.

Comment: I need to steer clear of those 5 followers.

Comment: It's clear that you are one of them @Gigi

Comment: There are 2 comments on this post so far that doesn't include the word '*clear*'... It's ***clear***, that everyone likes puns here...

Answer (score 6):

You question is understandable, explicit, coherent, and unambiguous. It's good to examine this situation in an unclouded way, and be unrestricted and unhindered about our goals.

I agree that we should unburden the site of such a tag, and get over this hurdle as soon as possible. I acquit you of all wrongdoing with this request, which has been endorsed by my agents.

Comment: puninate request.

Answer (score 3):

The correct usage and meaning of this tag isn't the least bit [clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clear); what *is* pretty [clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clear) is that this tag should be burninated. Its use adds absolutely nothing of value about what the tagged questions actually contain.

The tag wiki is further proof:

> Do not use. Purpose unclear and current usage ambiguous.